# Running an application as an Administrator without prompting for elevation

Tags: inno-setup, uac, elevation

I'm installing my app using Innosetup, to launch when then user logs in using SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. How can I start the app as if I've right-clicked and selected Run as Administrator, without the UAC prompt?

Comment: This is not possible. That's why the UAC is there. If possible, then only the hacky way and from the application which would run your setup, not from InnoSetup installation itself. Do you really need administrator privileges for your setup ? If not, then it's very easy to configure your setup script.

Comment: @TLama My app must lock-down the PC under certain conditions (disable task manager) which can't be done as a non-admin user. How would one implement this?

Comment: Simply do that via a Windows service.

Comment: @LexLi Well "Simply" rewriting the app as a service is an understatement :) It's a new feature on an existing production app. Looks like some people have some success in installing as adminsitrator and then setting the run parameter runasoriginaluser. Will report back if it works.

Answer (score 2):

With UAC enabled, any app that requires elevation will cause the prompt with no way to bypass it (Ignoring the setting to allow MS signed apps to elevate automatically)

You could always make your app only elevate when required, either via [running itself again](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shellexecute+%22runas%22) or via [COM elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=com+elevation).

As a side note, elevation/admin access should not be required for "general applications".

Comment: +1, elevation access should not be required for *general applications*, that's right, but if OP wants to *disable task manager* (quite suspicious anyway), then there won't be another way, I guess.